# custom sorting on column name

Tags: sorting

Here I have sample data like

```
Plan1 - 1
Plan1 - 3
Plan1 - 2
Plan1 - 5
Plan2 - 4
Plan2 - 1
```

I need to show like this

```
Plan1 - 1 - 0
Plan1 - 2 - 1
Plan1 - 3 - 2
Plan1 - 5 - 3
Plan2 - 1 - 0
Plan2 - 4 - 2
```

Can you please provide the solution in c# or sql query?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I've fixed your formatting a little, but your question is a bit unclear: what SQLplatform is this? What version? Your two lists don't really match, are they supposed to be the same list in a different order?

Comment: Or, perhaps, the same list with an unspecified formatting rule applied (in which case, knowing the rule would be critical).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY …), although

> Plan2 - 4 - 2

throws it off...
Assuming it should be

> Plan2 - 4 - 1

and assuming a simple table structure:

```
create table temp
(planName VARCHAR(5),
 ID TINYINT);

 insert into temp
VALUES
('Plan1',1),
('Plan1',3),
('Plan1',2),
('Plan1',5),
('Plan2',4),
('Plan2',1)
```

In SQL Server something like this ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69900/2)):

```
SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY planName ORDER BY ID))-1 AS RowNumber FROM #temp
```

In MySQL it's less fun ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69900d/17/0)):

```
select 
  planName,
  ID,
  RowNumber-1 as RowNumber
from 
(
  select 
    planName,
    ID,
    @row_number:=CASE
      WHEN @planName = planName THEN @row_number +1
      ELSE 1
    END AS RowNumber,
    @planName:=planName as setVar
  from temp
  cross join (SELECT @planName:=min(planName),@row_number:=0 from temp) as t
    order by planName, id
) t
```